# how to change border color, only with not selected and required ??? angularJS, select chosen

Tags: angularjs, select

how to change border color, only with not selected and required ???

this component on angularJS, is required, I need to change border color, while the user doent select an item, can I do this ???

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Cliente</label>
  <select chosen id="idCliente" name="idCliente" class="chosen-select"
          disable-search="false" ng-model="item.idCliente"
          ng-options="cli.Cliente for cli in clientes" required="">
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select.ng-invalid {
  border-color: red !important; 
}
```

Add the above CSS in the project border will be in red color, when validation fail